# Customizing Header in Default Theme of JQuery Mobile App

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on a JQuery Mobile app. I need to enlarge the font used for the title text. Whenever I enlarge the text size, the height of the ui-header bar grows. I do not want it to grow. Instead, I want the ui-header to stay the same size of the default ui-header. I just want to enlarge the text size. Currently, I have the following:

```
.t1 { color: blue; font-size:24pt; font-weight:normal; }
.t2 { color: white; font-size:24pt; font-weight:normal; }

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home dd-btn">Back</a>
  <h1><span class="t1">My</span><span class="t2">App</span></h1>
</div>
```

How do I change the font size without making the header grow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to modify `.ui-header .ui-title` rule changing top and bottom margin values. For example:

```
.ui-header .ui-title {
    margin: 0 30% 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pwqtm/1/